# How can I apply a "genie animation" to a CCSprite?

Tags: 2d, animation, sprites, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2D and following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials#cocos2d).

I want to animate a `CCSprite` with the genie effect that OS X uses for hiding windows to the dock and showing them again.

Here's an example from [an iOS library](https://github.com/liangzhimy/BCGenieEffect):

[image: example effect]

How can I do this in Cocos2D?

Comment: Please do *not* cross-post questions in the future. I've flagged your SO question for deletion, since this site is probably the more topical one.

Answer (score -1):

Use ccsprite with ccbadgenode in order fire number of frame of spite with moveto postion can change each frame interval with time .cccallfuntion is

```
-(void)playStarAnimation
{
    Animation *anim = [Animation node];
    sp = [anim playAnimCCSpriteWithFileName:@"STARS~ipad" frameName:@"STARS" Layer:physicsLayer From:1 To:42 Delay:1.0/20.0 Loop:4 Position:CGPointMake(512, 750) TAG:STARS_ANIM];        
}

CCSequence *seq5 = [CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:5.3],
        [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playStarAnimation)], nil];
[self runAction:seq5];
```

Comment: `Use ccsprite with ccbadgenode in order fire number of frame of spite with moveto postion can change each frame interval with time .cccallfuntion is` Please take the time to reword this into something a bit more readable.